# mat-checkbox - how to get value from disabled checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I need help in getting the value of disabled checkbox. I have two level of users, so for admins, checkbox should be available and for regulars users disabled. I have that case solved, but I have a problem when regular user submit the form, because value of "isActive" is undefined. Thats because its disabled... After some googling, I tried adding another input which is hidden, but thats not working too... I tried several things but none of them its working.

```
    <mat-checkbox class="mr-3" color="primary" [checked]="user.isActive" name="isActive" [ngModel]="user.isActive" [disabled]="!isAdmin">
        Active
    </mat-checkbox>

    <mat-checkbox hidden="true" name="isActive" [(ngModel)]="user.isActive"></mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: if you use Template driven form it's extrange, for me work in my stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcehzg?file=src/app/checkbox-overview-example.html, if use ReactiveForm use getRawValue(), see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getRawValue BTW, if use ngForm, try `myForm.form.getRawValue()`

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks, getRawValue() is working, but I have 10 more input fields inside the form and I need all those value to post to my backend as JSON. My backend function have frombody property.

Answer (score 0):

WHy not you just set the value of that checkbox programmatically at the time of sending form data to backend, this is just a simple technique if value is disabled then create a check at time of sending info and then you can just add your desired value in the form.